# Adding std::string* to ListBox

Tags: c++, winforms

I am trying to add an std::string* to a list and after a few hours of searching I could not figure it out. Here is my code:

```
std::string* getName(int Instance) {
    return (std::string*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));
}
for (auto &i : getChildren(Players)) {
    this->playerList->Items->Add(getName(i));
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `return (std::string*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));` Huh?? Where did you got that sample from?

Comment: This code looks super hazardous. What if `int` isn't large enough to hold a pointer? What kind of magic number is `0x28`? Why do you have a pointer to an `std::string` in the first place..?

Comment: Do you get an error trying to run this? If not then its probably the getName function and that uhhh, interesting return code.

Comment: @Someone the getName is the main issue. I couldn't get that to work either

Comment: If you could explain what the getName function is supposed to do maybe we could help you. Also try printing the string instead of adding it to items to help debug it.

Comment: @Someone its a pointer to the name of something in a processes memory

Comment: So Instance is actually a pointer?

Comment: @Someone its an address in memory yes

Comment: The only advice I can give you is to replace it with a real pointer.

Comment: @Someone its not static

Comment: If you're reading some other processes memory there could be a dozen things that could go wrong. I don't think people online can debug this for you based on just the code. You'll have to break into that with a proper debugger, see what exactly `Instance` points to and figure out if it makes sense to do what you're doing.

Comment: I agree with every warning so far that this code is probably not going to be stable, but I have to ask, what is it doing that convinces you it is not working?  is it crashing?  is it adding random characters to your list?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your

```
std::string* getName(int Instance) {
    return (std::string*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));
}
```

like this:

```
char* getName(int Instance) {
    return (char*)(PBYTE(Instance) + 0x28);
}
```